# querying my objects from db using profile id

Tags: django

`

```
class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)

class Course(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    tutor = models.ForeignKey(Tutor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



def Courses(request):
    current_user = request.user
    print(current_user.id)
    courses = Course.objects.filter(students__id=current_user.id)
    return render(request, 'e-learning/courses.html', {'courses':courses})
```

`I have a model student that is related to a model course via many to many relationship. i want to query all the courses related to the current logged in user, who is a student.

Answer (score 0):

Since `current_user.id` points to the if of `User`, and `students__id` compares with the id for `Student`, try making the following change:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(students__user__id=current_user.id)
```

Comment: one last question, how can i make tutor field in the courses object to refer to the current logged in user or the creator of the course by default.?